# C# Interview Preparation - References?

Tags: c#, interview

This is a specific question relating to C#. However, it can be extrapolated to other languages too.

While one is preparing for an interview of a C# Developer (ASP.NET or WinForms or ), what would be the typical reference material that one should look at?

Are there any good books/interview question collections that one should look at so that they can be better prepared?

This is just to know the different scenarios. For example, I might be writing SQL Stored Procedures and Queries, but I might stumble when asked suddenly

Given an Employee Table with the following column(s).

EmployeeId, EmployeeName, ManagerId

Write a SQL Query which will get me the Name of Employee and Manager Name?

NOTE: I am not asking for a Question Bank so that I can learn by rote what the questions are and reproduce them (which, obviously will NOT work!)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=.net+interview

Comment: @o.k.w: +1 for a Brilliant Answer! Awesome!

Comment: Vote to Close - although old its attracted new answers and the format of SO does not suit this style question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [Scott Hanselman's blog post on "What Great .NET Developers Ought to Know"](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WhatGreatNETDevelopersOughtToKnowMoreNETInterviewQuestions.aspx).

From there you should be able to figure out how to search and study based on the concepts he mentions there.

Comment: Just a shame that it's really outdated these days imo.

Comment: @cyberzed - The sections dealing with specific .NET technologies may be a little outdated, but the core concepts haven't changed.

Comment: Agreed :) might have been a bit fast on the trigger, but there are so many areas that should be covered as well/instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is one really important thing to notice (as metioned on DotNetRocks show 608)...usually you wanna hire a guy that knows concepts and algorithms over a language specialist.

Know stuff like... IoC, Design patterns and stuff like that. It doesn't really matter if you know how to do really tricky 10 nested Linq queries if you don't know how to bring bread on the table in a flexible manner...I actually think that the main focus is know allot more about how to create good solutions over how the language can do this and that.

Comment: IoC is Inversion of Control...for the benefit of others.